# How to use an if else statement and not apply it or skip when a value from the column is equal to X in R?

Tags: r, list, if-statement

For example I have a column of values

```
 unique(df$Animals)

 "Giraffe","Elephant", "Lion","Cheetah","Dingo"
```

I want the conditional statement to completely skip when df$Animal is equal to "Dingo"

```
 df$Spotted<-ifelse(!is.na(df$Animals),
                         "Yes", "No")
```

Normally the script would assign Yes to all values which i am ok, but i don't want it to even read or go over when it is Dingo.

Comment: What is the expected output, given your example data?

Comment: expected output is blank for dingo. meaning the script skips over when df$Animals is dingo,

Comment: @user35131 You should _accept_ one of the two answers given here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a nested `ifelse` here:

```r
df$Spotted <- ifelse(df$Animals == "Dingo", "Dingo",
                     ifelse(is.na(df$Animals), "No", "Yes"))
```

Comment: I guess that works. i was hoping for a short function. My actual scenario deals with more columns

Comment: @user35131 Look into using the `case_when` function from the `dplyr` package.  Anyway, I can only answer whatever question you actually ask, which I have done above.

Comment: I'll try a more specific version of the question. I thought when i said skip it was enough though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell R what to write when it sees "Dingo". Using the lines below, `NA` will be introduced when "Dingo" is true.

```
df$Spotted<-ifelse(df$Animals != "Dingo", 
                   ifelse(!is.na(df$Animals), "Yes", "No"), NA)
```